# How to calculate in CSS?

Tags: css, css3

I want to make CSS like this

```
Width : 80%;
Height : (width-30%);
```

but I do not know, in order to measure **height: width-30%**. I've been using calc() but still can not

Comment: CSS is not a programming language so you cannot do it that way.

Comment: At this point, that's not possible with just css. You'll need javascript

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be looking for a fixed aspect ratio box.   That is possible in CSS, but not with calculations.    Instead you have to use some trickery.   Padding in CSS is always based on the width of the box.  You can use bottom padding on a pseudo element to force the height to be 30% less than the width.

```
.mybox {
  width: 80%;
}
.mybox:before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 70%;
}
.mybox:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Adapted from [Tomas Mulder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/483254/tomas-mulder)'s anwer to [Responsively change div size keeping aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121090/responsively-change-div-size-keeping-aspect-ratio)

Comment: Although this looks like LESS / SASS syntax?

Comment: @w3d, yes I copied the wrong thing.  Updated the answer now.